# `initialize` seems to check the arguments given to `new`

Tags: ruby, new-operator, initializer

I am looking at this code:

```
class Mo
  def new(indy, rome = 1)
    initialize(indy, rome)
  end
  def initialize(indy, rome)
    ...
  end
end

Mo.new(2)
```

I get this output:

```
test.rb:6:in `initialize': wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)   (ArgumentError)
```

If I add the default value for `rome` in the definition to `new`, it works:

```
class Mo
  def new(indy, rome = 1)
    initialize(indy, rome)
  end
  def initialize(indy, rome = 1)
    ...
  end
end

Mo.new(2)
```

Why?

Comment: Are you sure you "add[ed] the default value for rome in the definition to new"? It looks to me that you added it to `initialize`.

Comment: What does this have to do with [tag:new-operator]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Mo.new(2)` calls the method `Mo.new`, which by default calls the method `Mo#initialize` with the single argument `2` that it received, but your `Mo#initialize` expects two arguments.

Answer (score 4):

No need for `new` method, because `initialize` is "middleware" for allocating (creating) ruby object

```
class Mo
  def initialize(indy, rome = 1)
    @indy = indy
    @rome = rome
  end
end
i = Mo.new(2)
```

This means ruby does not enter in `new` method

You can check it by:

```
puts Mo.method(:new).source_location
# => nil
```

but you are able to override `self.new` in you `Mo` class

```
def self.new(indy, rome = 1)
end
```

then

```
p Mo.method(:new).source_location
# =>["mo.rb", 2]
```

And it does not enter in `initialize` method then

P.S.
It's not good practice, but if you want to execute you code, you should call

```
Mo.new(2).new(3)
```

because your `new` is `Mo` instance method

Comment: This does not answer the question.

Comment: Just a quick question. Is that mainly due to the "super" call in the end?

Answer (score 3):

When you write a code like

```
Class Foo
  def new
    ...
  end
end
```

You define an instance method for the object with class Foo. But when you create a new instance, you call a class' method `new`. If you want to rewrite method `Foo.new`, you should  write like:

```
Class Foo
  def self.new
    ....
  end
end
```

But actually it is a bad idea to declare your own method `new` for classes